# How to include GLUT in compiling clang

Tags: c, xcode, macos, glut

I have problem. Im compiling following c-file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

int main() {

return 0;
}
```

commands:

```
clang -framework GLUT main.c
clang -F/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/ main.c
clang -F/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/GLUT main.c
```

and i get error:

```
fatal error: 'GLUT/glut.h' file not found
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
```

How properly to include glut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you for some reason doesn't have GLUT framework on your machine. I have no errors compiling your example on my machine (10.8.4). Take a look at [this how-to](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/courses/eecs487/glut-howto/#mac) for some additional info

**Edit**
Don't use custom compilers packages. Install Command Line Tools to use compiler in terminal or run it via [xcrun](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcrun.1.html)

Comment: No, i have GLUT framework on my machine. when i attach glut to my project through xcode all ritght. im installed clang via following pkg https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer because after installing xcode command did not appear in terminal

Comment: Try to install command line tools to use clang in terminal. Or run clang from xcode environment using xcrun utility: `xcrun clang -framework GLUT main.c`

Comment: "Try to install command line tools to use clang in terminal" @cody, please details

Comment: thank you very much for help. im decided my problem. im uninstalled xcode and gcc.pkg command sudo /Library/Developer/Shared/uninstall-devtools --mode=all and then downloaded and installed Command Line Tools (OS X Mountain Lion) for Xcode - April 2013 from [is there](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/)

Comment: ok, not only clang, as well as clang++, gcc, g++. if im not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

This command should work:

```
clang -F/System/Library/Frameworks -framework GLUT main.c
```

The `-F/System/Library/Frameworks` specifies the **path to** the framework(s), and the `-framework GLUT` specifies which framework(s) to include.

Comment: yes, this command should work, im agree. i tried it to use, but fail. Problem is decided, read answer by @cody and my comment to it. Thank.